# Ferrite beads for a pam8403 board

Tags: amplifier, sound, emi-filtering

I can't figure out the EMI part of the datasheet for the PAM8403 chip.
Which ferrite beads should I use for amplifier output? Does anyone know any specific models of ferrite beads?
This is what the datasheet says

> Most applications require a ferrite bead filter as shown in Figure 2. The ferrite filter reduces EMI of around 1 MHz and higher. When selecting a ferrite bead, choose one with high impedance at high frequencies, and low impedance at low frequencies.

PAM8403 Datasheehttps://www.elecrow.com/download/PAM8403-datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PAM8403H-EV Board User Guide](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Part-Support-Files/PAM8403/PAM8403-User-Guide.pdf) has some part numbers:

[image]

[Diodes Incorporated PAM8403](https://www.we-online.com/en/components/icref/diodes-incorporated/PAM8403-Buck) is the Wurth page which has a link to the [spec sheet](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/742792037.pdf) the suggested ferrite beads.

As well as the ferrite beads shown in the EMI part of the datasheet for the PAM8403 chip, the PAM8403H-EV Board User Guide also shows some 1 nF capacitors as part of the EMI filter.

While I haven't designed a product which uses a PAM8403, the manufacturer's reference designs for ICs are usually a good starting point for supporting components.